# google places autocomplete suggestion trigger after X characters

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I am attempting to limit the display of suggestions for the Google Place Autocomplete API.

Since the Google API charges a API Call per character entered in the field, I would like to restrict the suggestions to only be shown after X amount of characters have been entered.

My initialization of the autocomplete is as standard as it gets.

```
 var input = document.getElementbyId('Searchbox');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.autocomplete(input)
```

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read the length of a string in javascript using `length`.

```
var input = document.getElementById("Searchbox");
if(input.length > 3)
{
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.autocomplete(input);
}
```

In this example, the `autocomplete`-function will only be fired if the input has length 4 or higher.

Also, I recommend that you cache results for as long as you like, to avoid useless charges.

Comment: Thanks!! just enough information to get me started.

Comment: I'm sorry I downvoted the selected answer. Solution described sets the initialization of the Autocomplete feature once at least 3 chars have been entered. But subsequently, the Autocompletion will happen on every keystroke within the input, no matter how many chars are actually entered.

Comment: @ffrey for it, you must implement the code into a function that fires each time the user hit a key.